# Update an Array of Objects in React State

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, react-state-management

I am currently having trouble updating my array of objects in the ReactJS state and I cannot figure it out. I do not want to use a database or redux and really new to react.
If the Objects in userData array have keys to identify each,  I could have done something like userData[key] = data. But in this case, I have no idea how to access the exact object that was passed to the form field when the edit button is clicked. Please Help. Thank you

Here is my code.

```
//This is a contact management application

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import ContactPage from "./components/ContactPage";
import ContactForm from "./components/ContactForm";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    email: "",
    address: "",
    imag: "",
  });

  // declear a new state varaible to store data
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userD")) || []
  );

  //declear a useEffect to store state locally on each change
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("userD", JSON.stringify(userData));
  }, [userData]);

  function handleChange(e) {
    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;

    setData({
      ...data,
      [name]: value,
    });
  }
/* Here is where I have a problem. onSubmit, I want to check all the contacts in the userData array, If it does not exist then push it there (Using the phoneNumber as a unique identifier). I cannot figure out how to update the exact same object in the array if the phoneNumber already exist in the userData array*/

  function handleSubmit(data) {
    let phoneNumberArr = userData.map((d) => d.phoneNumber);
    if (phoneNumberArr.indexOf(data.phoneNumber) === -1) {
      setUserData([...userData, data]);
    }else {
          }

    setData({
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
      email: "",
      address: "",
      imag: "",
    });
  }

  function handleDelete(index) {
    if (window.confirm("Click Ok if you want to delete or Cancle to exit")) {
      setUserData(userData.filter((d) => userData.indexOf(d) !== index));
    }
  }

  function handleEdit(info) {
    setData({
      firstName: info.firstName,
      lastName: info.lastName,
      phoneNumber: info.phoneNumber,
      email: info.email,
      address: info.address,
      imag: info.imag,
    });
  }

  function handleAddNew() {
    setData({
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
      email: "",
      address: "",
      imag: "",
    });
  }
```

Comment: is `userData` an array? calling `userData[key]` wont access what you want as an array would use an index vs an explicit key. If you changed the model to be an object where you store users data by a key that would make a lot of sense. If you keep the array you can find an individual users data with a find method. `userData.find( user => user.key === <key im looking for> )`

Comment: If you would share broader code sample (preferably, within some live environment, like [codesandbox](https://condesandbox.io) or [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)) that would've helped to suggest some relevant solutions. So far, I would recommend to introduce `id` property to uniquely address each user record (and access it, e.g. with [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)) and consider using [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) to modify your multi-part user records.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `data` argument passed to `handleSubmit` is a an object with a `phoneNumber` key, it's quite easy to check if it exists in the userData array using javascript's [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
// Tests whether at least one user in the array has the same phone number as `data`
const userSeenBefore = userData.some(user => user.phoneNumber === data.phoneNumber);

if (!userSeenBefore) {
    setUserData([...userData, data]);
}
```